# How can I make navigation work again in Google Maps?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, google-maps-navigation, maps

Device: Samsung Galaxy S2

For quite some time, I've been using Google Maps and Navigation. It worked fine with several app updates, until this week. Google Maps updated, and now Navigation crashes as soon as it actually needs to navigate.

At one moment I really needed it, as I was having a business appointment. You can imagine how disappointed I became.

How do I fix this, aside from using a different navigation app?

Comment: If you haven't already, you should report the crash to Google by clicking "Report" when you get the "has stopped" dialog. If they don't know it happens, they can't fix it.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix is `Settings-> apps-> all apps-> google maps-> uninstall update`

Answer (score 0):

As of this answer Google maps navigation is working fine. I have used it without incident. Also street view is working much better.

We'll see how future updates hold up for navigation.